# extract a column if using %in% operator in R+

Tags: r, subset

I have two datasets- testdata (744 records) with state and average as two columns and extractdata(19 records) with state column in R.I want to select 'average column' from testdata for all states which are present in state column of extractdata. Please suggest an R code.Thanks
something like this -

```
testdata            extractdata

state  average      state
CA    2345.67       AB
LA     4587.90      AE
TX     8521.12      TN 
...so on            KL
                    ..so on
```

I tried -

```
exavg=subset(testdata,(ex$State)%in%(testdata$State),select=c(Average))
```

but didnt work.

Comment: -1 for showing no effort to solve this problem on your own.

Comment: and for saying *but didnt work* without showing any error message or other output. How is this useful?

Comment: @SimonO101 by didnt work i meant it didnt give the desired output instead of throwing an error message . It didnt check for the condition and resulted as average for all states.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
exavg <- testdata[testdata$State %in% ex$State, "Average"]
```

Observe that:

1. Brackets are better suited for subsetting a dataframe;
2. The result of `%in%` has the same length of its *left* input, so you must put the `testdata` column to the left, to avoid length mismatch;
3. You can only refer to columns by *unquoted* name when using `$`, as in `ex$State`, otherwise you must pass the name as a string.